# How to make UITableViewCell stick to last position

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

How can I make a `UITableViewCell` stick to the bottom of the `UITableView` it belongs to no matter what?

The row can no longer be moved or edited (because I configured `canMoveRowAtIndexPath:` and `canEditRowAtIndexPath:` to do so) but the rows above it can still be moved below it. I want the last row to always be the last.

The array that acts as a datasource contains instances of a custom class I made. However I would like the content of the last cell to be a `NSString`. For example `@"Last row..."`.

So I want fixed content (I achieved this by removing the edit option for the row) and fixed position (always last no matter what).

I would like to know if there is a way of achieving this without a table footer.

Is it possible? How?

Thank you.

Comment: If it's just a simple text cell, what about placing `UIView` with `UILabel` inside on top of tableview, and position it to the bottom of tableview. You can also add "empty cell" as a last cell of the same height to ensure that all cells are visible when scrolled to the bottom of tableview.

Comment: I agree with @teamnorge, if you don’t want to add an empty cell, you could alter the tableview’s bottom constraint

Comment: I don't mind doing it in a cell. Actually I'd prefer to have an actual cell rather than another view on top. So if u have any idea of how to do it with a cell please share. Also, modify the table's bottom constraint how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am learning iOS programming right now by following a tutorial book. I encountered same question as yours. I found the solution on the book's forum. Here I post the solution for you.
After you configure the `canMoveRowAtIndexPath:`, I only post the remaining part which is also the tricky part for you.

The person who wrote the solution said:"***the main thing I tried to deal with is stopping other items moving up the last one as well as it being able to be edited***"
Remember, when moving a row, you should report the move to its data source by sending the message: `tableView:moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:`
So first you should implement this method in a TableViewController like this

```
    -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath

    {
    if(destinationIndexPath.row == [yourRowArray count]
    {
    return;
    }
    else{
    originally moving method you implemented before;
    }
    }
```

Secondly, "***This is the important bit, we need to ensure if you try and set the proposed index to be the bottom item that it fails and goes back to the source index path.***" by the poster in the forum.

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toProposedIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)proposedDestinationIndexPath
{
    if( sourceIndexPath.section != proposedDestinationIndexPath.section )
    {
        return sourceIndexPath;
    }
    else
    {
        if (proposedDestinationIndexPath.row == [yourRowArray count]) {
            return sourceIndexPath;
        } else {
            return proposedDestinationIndexPath;
        }
    }
}
```

Finish! Simple right? Then you will find without a table footer, only use a simple text cell, the last cell can not be moved and edited and can never be knocked out of the last position.